# Refresh fragment by Tag not ID

Tags: android, android-layout

I create the following fragment in "ActionBarMain.java"

```
    FragMent1 fram1;

FragmentTransaction fragMentTra = null;

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if (tab.getText().equals("Collection")) {
        try {
            rl.removeAllViews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        fram1 = new FragMent1();
        fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
        fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1);
        fragMentTra.commit();
```

}

```
//And in here I create a new activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddBookActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
```

So naturally I should be able to perform the `findFragmentByTag(fram1)`

Now I am in the "AddBookActivity" and have added a new item to an arraylist that `fram1` prints out in a `simple_list_item_1` so now I want to refresh fram1, how do I do that in AddBookActivity??

```
//AddBookActivity.java
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addBook:
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment newFragment = new FragMent1();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //How do I find out the fragment id from findFragmentByTag(fram1)????
                transaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_id, newFragment);//Whats the id, I have the Tag that is fram1
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                return true; 
            case R.id.cancel:
                super.finish(); 
                return (true);

            }

            return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findFragmentByTag` takes a `String` as a parameter, not a `Fragment`

so you would use

```
fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");
```

to add, and replace using

```
transaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_id, newFragment, "fram1");
```

to find the fragment, use

```
findFragmentByTag("fram1");
```

Whether that will update your list is another matter, since the code you posted does not address that.

EDIT:

Your `Activity` can load multiple `Fragments`, and therefore the `Activity` layout will depend on the screen size.  Simplest use is that it is only large enough for one `Fragment`.  This `Fragment` is a `FragmentList` or it contains a `ListView`.  The list requires an `Adapter` to bind the data to the list.  Simple example is a `ArrayAdapter` of type `String` e.g. `ArrayAdapter<String>`.  You assign the `ListView` to use the `ArrayAdapter` as its data source.  You can then change the `ArrayAdapter`s underlaying data (`ArrayList<String>` or `String[]`) directly (requires the adapter to be notified of the change) or via the adapter itself.  More complex views can be achieved by extending a adapter class.

I suggest looking at `ListView` and `FragmentList` SDK samples.

Comment: But how do I use "transaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_id, newFragment, "fram1");" if I don't know what "your_fragment_id" is?

Comment: findFragmentByTag("fram1") returns a fragment and not an ID

Comment: "your_fragment_id" is the id of the existing `Fragment` or placeholder.  you need to read the documentation...

Comment: Thank you, As you said the list didn't update, I created a new Object in each fragment/Activity instead of passing them through, have to look into that =)

Comment: I'll update my answer, since you accepted it, to hopefully give you a better understanding